# How to scoll down a web element in selenium using java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Javascript which is used to scroll the web element . 
I want to convert it to selenium + java code. 
I tried using java script executor but somehow I'm not able to get the desired result.
Here's the javascript that is working fine for me .

```
var x = window.content.document.getElementsByClassName("_PMgtb");
x[0].scrollTop += 100;
```

Comment: In most of cases, before performing any action on a web element selenium scroll the page to make the element visible. No need to do it unless required for specific scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions" class to move to an element:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.class("_PMgtb"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

*JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

WebElement element = null;

element = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return document.getElementsByClassName("_PMgtb")[0];", element);

js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];",element, 100);*